# Lua pattern for parsing strings with optional part

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have to parse a string in the form `value, value, value, value, value`. The two last values are optional. This is my code, but it works only for the required arguments:

```
Regex = "([^,])+, ([^,])+, ([^,])+"
```

I'm using `string.match` to get the value into variables.

Comment: Lua pattern isn't regular expression. What exactly do you want to match? Use specific example to explain, what is the input and what is expected output.

Comment: I don't know lua but isn't exist `split`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're splitting the string by a comma, use `gmatch`:

```
local tParts = {}
for sMatch in str:gmatch "([^,]+)" do
    table.insert( tParts, sMatch )
end
```

Now, once the parts are stored inside the table; you can check if the table contains matched groups at indexes `4` and `5` by:

```
if tParts[4] and tParts[5] then
    -- do your job
elseif tParts[3] then
    -- only first three matches were there
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) you can't make a capturing group optional, and also you are not able to use a logical OR operator. So the answer is: It isn't possible.